# VSCode built-in snippets fail to to show when consecutive letters are typed

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

[image]
If I type one letter of the trigger/prefix, the snippet suggestion works to show the built-in snippets from extensions. But, once I type the next letter in the trigger/prefix...the built-in snippet from the extension is gone. Meaning, it is no longer found anywhere in the dropdown list (you won't find it by scrolling). [image].
Here is a snapshot confirming that the trigger/prefix is removed from the list[image]
I found that with some built-in snippets from extensions, if I type out the entire word, it will reappear.  For example, if I want: 'trycatch', it will be populated in the list when I type 't', disappear when I have typed 'tr', but then reappear when the entire trigger/prefix is typed.

How can i get a built-in snippet from an extension to show in snippet search when 2 or more letters of the trigger/prefix are typed?  I am using version 1.75.0

I tried looking at the docs of VSCode, [but it's too simple to help](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets). I tried looking at my settings (keyword: snippets) and play around with any possibilities, but nothing seemed to fix it. Any google search comes up empty as well.

Comment: You still didn't add version info for relevant extensions.

Comment: the same problem happens with Emmet commands, if it is a possible Emmet command you don't get any other suggestion, no snippets that might match, give your snippet prefixes an unused prefix that will not trigger suggestions from the LanguageServer or Emmet or ...., use a prefix like `xxraf`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: honestly, you might be better off creating an issue ticket [on the VS Code GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues) instead asking for help here. This smells like bug.

Comment: Known problem, already fixed in Insiders, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75340430/836330