# Visual Studio Code's 1.75.0 update is disrupting autocompletion

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have a user snippet configured in Visual Studio Code. Let's take one of the items in this snippet: one with the prefix `imp`.

Now, prior to the recent VSCode update, as soon as I did something like the following.

[image: VSCode snapshot]

it automatically showed the autocompletion box to me (I didn't have to press `Ctrl` + `Space` to activate it), as shown below:

[image: vscode snapshot]

---

But now after the update, something strange has happened. When I type in just `im`, obviously, it shows me the `<img>` autocompletion suggestions as shown below:

[image]

But when I continue to type the full thing `imp`, the autocompletion box gets hidden. It's only when I press `Ctrl` + `Space` that I get the autocompletion box again.

**What is the reason for this problem and how to fix it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue exactly, which led me to look to see if it has been reported on github.  It has, see [Snippets gone from IntelliSense](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/173244).

From [same issue as above](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/173244#issuecomment-1415824770):

> I have pushed a fix for next insiders and I have pitched this for the
> 1.75.1 recovery release

It is in today's Insiders (I just tested it) 02/03/2023.

So you can either try the Insiders Build now or wait for the Recovery Release.  And continue to use the manual trigger of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> in the meantime.

As @WayneBloss mentions in a comment below, **disabling** the `snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions` setting might fix the issue.

Comment: So you mean that it would be fixed by Monday, not before that?

Comment: It has been fixed but it won't be pushed to users until Monday's Insider Build.  A recovery build like v1.75.1 will come out later to Stable, hard to say when, usually about a week roughly.

Comment: So if I want to install any 'beta' version, I can't, right?

Comment: So, isn't there any way to customize this for the time being, in VSCode while the team works on the push.

Comment: So I just got another Insiders Build and it looks like the fix has been included!

Comment: So for the time being, it means that I have to settle with this bug.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/ - you can run Insiders, which is basically a beta build refreshed daily and move projects back and forth between Insiders and Stable.  But of course, Insiders may have issues...  But it is usually pretty solid.  [Although this completion issue was not caught by user using the Insiders Build.]

Comment: But Mark how can I use this Insider? It seems that I have to perform a complete reinstall. Isn't there any way to just update to the Insider?

Comment: When I set `snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions` setting to false it works fine on 1.75 - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/173387#issuecomment-1421048871

Comment: @WayneBloss I'll add your comment to the answer so people are more likely to see it.  Thank you for the information.