# ES7+ React/Redux/React-Native snippets not working in VS code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I need help with VS-Code.

Till last night while typing "rafc" in a React document would generate the ES7 arrow function code snippet for the respective React-Redux file using the extension "ES7+ React/Redux/React-Native snippets". But from today morning, while I am typing rafc, it is behaving weirdly & giving irrelevant suggestion of "ReadableStreamDefaultController" which I don't have any usage for right now.

Problem is, I can't break up with code snippets right now as it does the boring task of generating the boilerplate code.

A snapshot of the problem is attached below.[This is the suggestion given by VS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmrnk.png)

I have tried restarting, updating, and everything else that I could find on google. But it is still the same.

Can someone help me with this weird problem?

Comment: Welcome! Looks like a possible duplicate of [VSCode built-in snippets fail to to show when consecutive letters are typed](/q/75331646). Exact same snippet used as an example to boot :P sadly, no answers there yet.

Comment: Did you recently get your VS Code updated? Coincidentally, VS Code 1.75 release a day before this was posted (2023-02-03 7:50pm) And if so, was it working before the update? If so, file an issue ticket or look to see if someone has already filed [on their issue tracker](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues).

Comment: you can use the command **Insert Snippet** to bypass the autocomplete

Comment: Found the problem however i still have no solution.
after disabling the built-in Typescript and Javascript language features extension the snippets worked normaly.
the issue happens when auto suggestions are shown during typing, if you close the suggestions popup and open it back up the snippets would be shown.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75340430/836330 Probably same issue.  Known, fixed in Insiders.

Answer (score 1):

I'm uninstall ES7+ React/Redux... and install again, after that snippet rafc, clg ... are working again....

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).