# ES7 React/Redux/GraphQL/React-Native snippets suddenly started working wierdly

Tags: visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wvfu.png)
I have installed ES7 React/Redux/GraphQL/React-Native extension in vs code but it is not working. Instead some other suggestion are comming. and I dont know what is it. Previously the extension was working fine.

I tried pasting "reactSnippets.settings.importReactOnTop": false, this line in settings.json. When i reload the vs code the extension seems to be working for a second and after that i am not getting any snippet recomendations from the extension.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75343574/es7-react-redux-react-native-snippets-not-working-in-vs-code

Comment: Probably https://stackoverflow.com/a/75340430/836330 - known issue, already fixed in Insiders.