# VScode php user snippet not showing at all in suggestions if it remotely matches an emmet tag

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code, code-snippets, emmet

In my vscode I have some handy user snippets but lately they don't properly show in suggestions when I want to use them. For example, I have a snippet called "dd" and another called "foreach". For the dd one, If I type only one d it appears in the suggestions but the moment that I type the second d it vanishes and I'm left with only the dd emmet sugestion for a dd html tag. In the foreach one, If I type "fo" it shows up normally, but the moment I type the "r" it also vanishes and I'm left with only the emmet suggestion for a form html tag.

Does anyone knows why this is happening and better yet how to solve it?

I have the muscle memory automatically type "dd + tab" and "for + tab" to use those, so it's not as simple as "just don't type that much".

Comment: how do you want to determine that now you want the snippet but next time you want the emmet command in case you type `dd + Tab`, give the snippet a prefix that does not trigger an emmet command

Comment: Probably this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75340430/836330

Comment: @Mark Yes! This seems to be the same problem, so I think it's just a matter of waiting vscode to fix it, right?

Comment: Yes, already fixed in the Insiders Build, Stable v1.75.1 will probably be released next week or so...